# Rake - running specific custom tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create a couple of rake tasks that I can call individually:

```
require 'rspec/core/rake_task'

namespace :grouped_tests do

desc "Run the Group A specs."
task :group_a => :spec
  puts "starting tests a"
  RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new do |t|
    t.pattern = "spec/helpers/*_spec.rb"
  end


desc "Run the Group B specs."
task :group_b => :spec
  puts "starting tests b"
  RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new do |t|
    t.pattern = "spec/views/*_spec.rb"
  end

end
```

But when I call the following:

```
rake grouped_tests:group_b
```

It still shows in the output (from the `puts`):

```
starting tests a
starting tests b
```

And it only runs the `:group_a`, even though I am calling `group_b`.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update your code as follow:

```
require 'rake'
require 'rspec/core/rake_task'

namespace :grouped_tests do
  namespace :helpers do
    desc "Run the Group A specs."
    RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:selective => "db:test:prepare") do |t|
      puts "starting tests a"
      t.pattern = "spec/helpers/*_spec.rb"
    end
  end

  namespace :views do
    desc "Run the Group B specs."
    RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:selective => "db:test:prepare") do |t|
      puts "starting tests b"
      t.pattern = "spec/views/*_spec.rb"
    end
  end
end

task :selective => ["grouped_tests:helpers:selective", "grouped_tests:views:selective"]
```

You can call the rake tasks as:

```
rake grouped_tests:helpers:selective
rake grouped_tests:views:selective
```

Comment: this didnt work, it didnt even run the specs at all, it did however only output one of the puts so it is running them indiviudally, but not running the specs it just stops, do I need the "=> :spec"

Comment: No, you don't need `=> :spec`. Updated the answer. Have a look

Comment: Does FileList search subfolders too?  so if Views had subfolders, how would I bring in those too?

Comment: Try `"spec/views/**/*_spec.rb"`

Answer (score -1):

I believe it is a syntax error, you are missing the `do` keyword:

```
task :group_a => :spec do
// Do your thing
end

task :group_b => :spec do
// Do your other thing
end
```

Comment: this doesnt work - it loads all the tests in the spec folder